# ERROR: has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'

Tags: angular, typescript, swiper.js

I am using Angular 11 and have encountered the following error when I added the swiper carousel to the project. I tried deleting and reinstalling node_modules but this did not solve the problem.

I have also tried changing the `enableIvy` setting in `tsconfig.lib.strong` `textprod.json` to this:

```
"enableIvy": false,
```

But that doesn't seem to have any effect.

It keeps showing the following error:

> Error: node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper-slide.directive.d.ts:24:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Angualr project/project1/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
> 24     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<SwiperSlideDirective, never>;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper-slide.directive.d.ts:25:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Angualr project/project1/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration'.
> 25     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<SwiperSlideDirective, "ng-template[swiperSlide]", never, { "virtualIndex": "virtualIndex"; "class": "class"; "autoplayDelay": "data-swiper-autoplay"; "zoom": "zoom"; }, {}, never>;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:250:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Angualr project/project1/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
> 250     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<SwiperComponent, never>;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:251:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Angualr project/project1/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

Something that confused me a lot in the text of the error refers to a place that does not exist:
`C:/Angualr project/project1/node_modules/@angular/core/core"`

Comment: Same problem here !

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Remove the unsupported package. Newer versions of angular requires packages to use the latest renderer as well. And instead of `npm i` use `npm ci` when retinstalling your modules to avoid accidentally upgrading packages. Double check if the package supports the angular version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue earlier, I was able to resolve this by carrying out these few steps:

1. deleted my node_modules folder
2. ran `npm i` on the command line.
3. lastly ran `ng serve`.